# Insertion sort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, insertion-sort

[Here is a REPL](https://repl.it/CSTs/10) of the code. The idea here is to learn how the basic insertion sort algorithm works rather than to use existing sort libraries.

How can it be clearer and more efficient?

```
function insertionSort(array)
{
    for(var i = 1; i < array.length; ++i)
    {
        var currentItem = array[i];

        for(var j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            if(array[j] <= currentItem) break;
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
        }

        array[j + 1] = currentItem;
    }

    return array;
}

//test
var initialArray = [ 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 5, 2, 5, 7, 8, 4, 7, 9 ];
var solutionArray = [ 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9 ];

var sortedArray = insertionSort(initialArray);

var passed = JSON.stringify(sortedArray)==JSON.stringify(solutionArray);
console.log('passed:' + passed);
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is an incomplete post. Please add some more to the question other than code. What would you like reviewed about your code?

Comment: @SirPython Hmm. I lack any particular questions other than wanting someone to review the code and to give his/her opinion. I think that this might be outside the scope of this StackExchange. Is that right?

Comment: Definitely not; your post is perfect here. I'm just saying questions with only code in the post aren't so well received. You could very well add "Any recommendations are welcome" at the bottom. And, you could even explain what the insertion sort is and how your code is accomplishing that.

Comment: Your code can be dramatically simplified by just writing `array.sort()` -> https://repl.it/CSTs/7

Comment: @Jonathan Good call. Indeed that's true. :) I updated my question to emphasize my interest in learning algorithms.

Comment: Your usage of pre-decrement `++i` is confusing, precisely because it makes no difference in this case, because it's not used within an assignment/expression context. I'd say stick with regular `i++` to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Good call @sweaver2112. Why break with convention if not to express some unusual intent.

Answer (score 2):

**Eliminating some unnecessary code**

Some programmers find `break` statements to be problematic. If you'd like to know more, here is a [programmers stack exchange question about breaks and continues](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/are-break-and-continue-bad-programming-practices).

You could easily eliminate your use of `break` by just changing the inner loop to the following:

```
for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0 && array[j] > currentItem; j--) {
  array[j + 1] = array[j];
}
```

This shortens your code a bit and condenses all the control flow logic of you loop into one spot.

---

You could shorten your code even further by eliminating the conditional `j >= 0`:

```
for (var j = i - 1; array[j] > currentItem; j--) {
  array[j + 1] = array[j];
}
```

However, this might obfuscate the code a bit.

*Note: This works because `array[-1]` will return `undefined` and `undefined > myVar` will always evaluate to false - [ECMAScript Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1)*

Comment: What do some programmers find problematic about `break` statements?

Comment: I've added a link to my answer that goes into depth on using breaks and continues. I'd offer an explanation of my own but it would not be as thorough.